# pandas group by with multiple agg not working on multiple columns

Tags: pandas, group-by, pivot

[file table need to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPocz.png)

I have a dataset where I need to report same exact image.

Sub-activity is int
project is a category " 3 project only"
status is block, complete, on going

is that doable in python or I should stay in excel.

```
df.pivot_table(values='Sub-activity', index='project', columns='STATUS', aggfunc=['sum','count'])
```

Comment: please provide a reproducible input and the matching expected output, not an image. If you want merged cells, use excel, else use MultiIndexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question requires an explicit reproducible example.

But to answer the *Excel-formatting* part, you can hack it using the [*Styler*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html) with [xlsxwriter](/questions/tagged/xlsxwriter) :

```
SN = "Sheet1" # adjust if needed

def fn_idx(color, va=False):
    fmt = (
        f"background-color:{color}; color:white; border:3px solid;"
        "border-color: black; text-align:center; font-weight: normal;"
    )
    return fmt + ("vertical-align: middle;" if va else "")

def fn(how=""):
    d = {"border": "3px solid", "text-align": "center"}
    if how=="as_string":
        return "".join(f"{k}: {v}; " for k, v in d.items()).strip()
    else:
        return d

xlstyles = {"bg_color": "#808080", "font_color": "white",
            "align": "center", "border": 2, "valign": "vcenter"}

with pd.ExcelWriter("file.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
    (df.style # use `.applymap_index` if you're on pandas<2.1.0
        .map_index(lambda _: fn_idx("#3a3838", va=True), axis=0, level=0)
        .map_index(lambda _: fn("as_string"), axis=0, level=1)
        .map_index(lambda _: fn_idx("#808080"), axis=1)
        .set_properties(**fn()).to_excel(writer))
    
    ws, fmt = writer.sheets[SN], writer.book.add_format(xlstyles)
    for idx, n in enumerate(df.index.names):
        ws.merge_range(0, idx, 2, idx, n, fmt)
    for idx, n in enumerate(df.columns.get_level_values(-1)):
        ws.merge_range(1, idx+2, 2, idx+2, n, fmt)

    ws.autofit() # xlsxwriter 3.0.6+
```

Output (*file.xlsx*) :

[image]

Used input :

```
print(df.to_dict("tight"))

{'index': [('project1', 'Sum of activity'),
  ('project1', 'Count of activity'),
  ('project2', 'Sum of activity'),
  ('project2', 'Count of activity')],
 'columns': [('Weekly', 'Received'),
  ('Weekly', 'On-Going'),
  ('Weekly', 'Completed'),
  ('Cumulative', 'Received'),
  ('Cumulative', 'On-Going'),
  ('Cumulative', 'Completed')],
 'data': [[15, 2, 13, 623, 5, 618],
  [10, 2, 8, 430, 5, 425],
  [25, 7, 18, 465, 7, 458],
  [23, 6, 17, 403, 6, 397]],
 'index_names': ['Main Activity', 'Sub-Activity'],
 'column_names': [None, None]}
```